Nullable Class Makes Int Nullable
I have a nullable class property:
public MyDTO? myDTO {get;set;}

Inside MyDTO, I have a int property:
public int RefreshRate {get;set;}

I want to use this property as a parameter to lets say pass into a Timer like so:
    var refreshRate = MyDTO?.RefreshRate;

    TruckSearchTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(async _ =>
    {
        if (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ...
        }
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    
    }), null, refreshRate, refreshRate);

However, adding the nullable ? turns my int property to a nullable int (int?). My question is, how do I get the int value from my nullable int? I've tried this:
refreshRate.Value;

But .Value isn't found. This is a NET8 Blazor web application.
I'm getting around it by simply checking if the object is null:
if (MyDTO is not null) { ... }


"But .Value isn't found." - can you please post the full error text?

But you should note that even if Value was found you would get NRE (or similar) when MyDTO is null.

Kind of an important nitpick... It doesn't make the property nullable.  That is, public int RefreshRate is an int.  It makes your local variable (var refreshRate) nullable.  Because it would have to be.  And then .Value would be how to access the raw value, though you'd want to check .HasValue first.

nvm, when I closed my tab and reopened my error was gone. I seem to have to do that often with Blazor. .Value is now working.

When MyDTO is null,  the whole thing becomes null.

You could se a default value though, like: var refreshRate = MyDTO?.RefreshRate ?? 1;

In fact I am wondering why you think so. In my project the refreshRate.Value is correct and the error comes because MyDTO is not initiated with an instance, so the usage is correct  with no error if MyDTO has an instance. If MyDTO is null without a instance, what is the meaning to retrieve the refreshRate.

Value should be found for an int?.  If you want to give it a default value when MyDTO is null, you can change it to something like this:
var refreshRate = MyDTO?.RefreshRate ?? 60;

That will ensure that refreshRate is an int rather than nullable int.


However, adding the nullable ? turns my int property to a nullable int
(int?)

No, that's not what's happening. Making a class nullablle does not turn its properties to their nullable kind.
The null-conditional operator ? is doing that to the local variable refreshRate:
var refreshRate = MyDTO?.RefreshRate; // var is int?

if you for a second forego the ? you'd only get a warning but compile:
int refreshRate = MyDTO.RefreshRate;

which shows that RefreshRate is still just int and not int?.
You will get null in the original example
var refreshRate = MyDTO?.RefreshRate;

not because RefreshRate is null, but because MyDTO is.
Whether you decide to use a default value for the case of MyDTO being null or not is up to you.
